# How to filter independent variables in decision-tree in R with rpart or party package

Tags: r, decision-tree, rpart, party

I am a SAS user and currently studying how to make decision tree using R-package.

I do have a good finding associated with each nodes, but now I'm facing 3 questions:

1. Can I start with a specific variable (top-to-bottom), say, categorical var like gender? ( I did it in FICO-Model builder but now I dont have it anymore)
2. I have a binary var(gender:1-Male/0-Female), but the nodes split at 0.5?(I tried change it to factor, but didn't work? Also I have a var "AGE", should I change the type to "xxx" instead of "numeric"?)
3. Based on cp value (below table), I set 0.0128 to prune the tree, but only two vars left, can I  choose to keep specific vars?( I do play with the numbers of cp, but the result is not changing )

[image]

[image]
[image]

```
#tree
library(rpart)
library(party)
library(rpart.plot)

#1
minsplit<-60
ct <- rpart.control(xval=10, minsplit=minsplit,minbucket = 
         minsplit/3,cp=0.01)  



 iris_tree <- rpart(Overday_E60dlq ~  .   
                ,

               data= x, method="class",   
               parms = list(prior = c(0.65,0.35), split = "information")
               ,control=ct) 



#plot split.

plot_tris<-rpart.plot(iris_tree, branch=1 , branch.type= 1, type= 2, extra= 
103,  
                  shadow.col="gray", box.col="green",  
                  border.col="blue", split.col="red",  
                  cex=0.65, main="Kyphosis-tree") 

plot_tris
#summary
summary(iris_tree)



#===========prune process=========
printcp(iris_tree)

##  min-xerror cp：  
fitcp<-prune(iris_tree, cp= 
iris_tree$cptable[which.min(iris_tree$cptable[,"xerror"]),"CP"])  


#cp table   
fit2<-prune(fitcp,cp= 0.0128 )

#plot fit2
rpart.plot(fit2, branch=1 , branch.type= 1, type= 2, extra= 103,  
       shadow.col="gray", box.col="green",  
       border.col="blue", split.col="red",  
       cex=0.65, main="Kyphosis fit2")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I don't think that one of the more popular tree packages in R has a built-in option for specifying fixed initial splits. Using the `partykit` package (successor to the `party` package), however, has infrastructure that can be leveraged to put together such trees with a little bit of effort, see: [How to specify split in a decision tree in R programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39844830/how-to-specify-split-in-a-decision-tree-in-r-programming/39870712#39870712)
2. You should use `factor` variables for unordered categorical covariates (like gender), `ordered` factors for ordinal covariates, and `numeric` or `integer` for numeric covariates. Note that this may not only matter in the visual display but also in the recursive partitioning itself. When using an exhaustive search algorithm like `rpart`/CART it is not relevant, but for unbiased inference-based algorithms like `ctree` or `mob` this may be an important difference.
3. Cost-complexity pruning does not allow to keep specific covariates. It is a measure for the overall tree, not for individual variables.