# How to specify multiple splits in R-studio using classification tree- ctree?

Tags: r, party, ctree

I'm using 'ctree' for classification tree ( categorical response variable; New, Replace). I already got help from other available answers and forced the model to start splitting based on 'Year'. I have four independent variables (including 'Year"). But the model just used one significant variable. So, I want to force the model to split into other nodes based on other parameters, too.

I got help from [How to specify split in a decision tree in R programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39844830/how-to-specify-split-in-a-decision-tree-in-r-programming) @Achim Zeileis

...

> ### decision tree with 'party' package
>
> ```
> library(partykit)
> set.seed(123)
> tr1<- ctree(new_ROWTS ~ Year, data = training )
> tr2<- ctree(new_ROWTS ~ Year + STI_OWTS_00+capacity_per_bed+system_type,
>     data = training,
>     subset = predict (tr1, type = "node")==2)
> tr3<- ctree(new_ROWTS ~ Year + STI_OWTS_00+capacity_per_bed+system_type,
>      data = training,
>      subset = predict (tr1, type = "node")==3)
> ...........
> ##Extract the raw node structure from all three trees, fix-up nood id:##
> fixids <-  function(x, startid = 1L) {
> id <- startid - 1L 
> new_node <- function (x) {
> id <<- id +1L
> if(is.terminal(x)) return(partynode(id, info = info_node(x)))
> partynode(id, 
>      split = split_node(x),
>       kids = lapply(kids_node(x),new_node),
>       surrogates = surrogates_node(x), 
>       info = info_node(x))
> }
> return (new_node(x))
> }
> no <- node_party(tr1)
> no$kids <- list (
>       fixids(node_party(tr2), startid = 2L),
>       fixids(node_party(tr3), startid = 3L)
> )
> no
> ............
> ##set up a joint model:##
> d <- model.frame(new_ROWTS ~ Year + 
>                  STI_OWTS_00+capacity_per_bed+system_type,
> data = training)
> tr <- party (no, data = d, 
>             fitted = data.frame(
>             "(fitted)" = fitted_node(no, data = d),
>             "(response)" = model.response(d), check.names = FALSE),
>              terms = terms(d),
>              ) 
> tr <- as.constparty(tr)
> ##Visualizing##
> plot(tr)
> ##This is the output: Leaf 1 (year) divided to two nodes :before 1998[2],
> and >aftre 1998 [3]. and node 3 splits to two [4] and [5]##
> [1] root
> |   [2] V2 <= 1 *
> |   [3] V2 > 1
> |   |   [4] V3 <= 10.52754 *
> |   |   [5] V3 > 10.52754 *
> ```

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear what you want. It appears that your predictors do not have enough predictive power to be included in the tree. Forcing splits despite non-significiance of the association with the dependent variable is probably not a very good solution.

If you want to see the structure of the tree when allowing splits at less strict singificance levels (default is `alpha = 0.05`), you can use something like `ctree(..., alpha = 0.8)` etc. See `?ctree_control` for further details. Whether or not the results of such a tree are useful for interpretation and/or prediction is a different question, though.

Comment: Thanks. I used alpha = 0.4 for the second tree (tr2) and a default alpha for tr3.  tr2 showed 2 more splits with the percentage of 'Replace' 'New'. But tr3 didn't show any percentage and showed empty boxes with n= 0!